# PySpark DataFrame creation with multiple files with and without header in same directory

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to create a dataframe from a directory with multiple files. Among these files, only one has header. I want to use the infer schema option to create the schema from the header.

When I am creating the DF using one file, it is correctly inferring the schema.

```
flights = spark.read.csv("/sample/flight/flight_delays1.csv",header=True,inferSchema=True)
```

But, when I am reading all the files in the directory, it is throwing this error.

```
flights = spark.read.csv("/sample/flight/",header=True,inferSchema=True)

18/04/21 23:49:18 WARN SchemaUtils: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema and the partition schema: `11`. You might need to assign different column names.

flights.take(5)

18/04/21 23:49:27 WARN Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 476, in take
        return self.limit(num).collect()
      File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 438, in collect
        port = self._jdf.collectToPython()
      File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
      File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
        raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
    pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Reference '11' is ambiguous, could be: 11#13, 11#32.;"
```

I know one workaround is to remove the header line, and define the schema manually, is there any other tactic to use infer schema on one file and then add other files to the DF?

Comment: Read it as a text file, remove the first line, then convert the rdd to a df with the headers you provide.

Comment: That is an option. However, after converting the RDD to DF, all the columns data types are showing as String. Whereas, if I am creating the DF from the CSV files, the original data types are intact(e.g. name sting, age int).

Comment: Can you try it out and show the output of printSchema()? How are you defining the schema? Are you using the StructType(Array(StructField('age', IntegerType())))?

Comment: how many files do you have ?

Answer (score 3):

I would advice you to do so :

```py
# First, you infer the schema from the file you know
schm_file = spark.read.csv(
    "/sample/flight/file_with_header.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True
)
# Then you use the schema to read the other files
flights = spark.read.csv(
    "/sample/flight/", header=False, mode="DROPMALFORMED", schema=schm_file.schema
)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I upvoted your answer. but seems like, I am not adult enough to upvote.

Comment: @mmopu can you accept the answer if it works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another way. but not dynamic enough for a huge number of files. I prefer the way @Steven has suggested.

```
df1 = spark.read.csv("/sample/flight/flight_delays1.csv",header=True,inferSchema=True)
df2 = spark.read.schema(df1.schema).csv("/sample/flight/flight_delays2.csv")
df3 = spark.read.schema(df1.schema).csv("/sample/flight/flight_delays3.csv")

complete_df = df1.union(df2).union(df3)
complete_df.count()
complete_df.printSchema()
```